# When I move windows between my 4k monitor and my 1080p monitor, the text in some windows get distorted. How can I avoid that?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, fonts

Example (the font size in the title became huge while the font size in the menu is tiny):

[image]

[image]

I use a GS76 Stealth 11UH laptop (4k monitor) running on Microsoft Windows 10 with a 1080p external monitor.

---

Settings of each monitor:

[image]

Monitor 1 (4k):

[image]

[image]

Monitor 2 (1080p):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the settings of each monitor?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, good idea, added.

Comment: That is pretty simple, moving objects between two different resolution monitors may cause that to happen, the other monitor is receiving the image in a quality it cannot handle

Answer (score 2):

One of your displays is set to 250%, Windows will generally respect and apply that, so most everything you see from Windows will look 'matching' each other in size.  However, each application has to handle this accordingly - even if 'handling' means to leave it alone so Windows handles it. Some applications developers think they are more clever, or they don't know any better, and use their own settings - resulting in incorrectly / differently scaled text or graphics.
In this case, maybe the top menu uses the windows scaling, and the submenu's font size is hard coded, so it doesn't scale.

As far as I know, there is little you can do to fix that, unless you know the developer.

This is a theory of course; you can verify it by setting the scaling to 100% and reboot. Of course, things will be very small, and you might not like it - but if the problem of inconsistency is gone, you know that this is the reason.

Maybe you can try starting the offending app under various *compatibility* setting, and that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know!